# haproxy: What are its uses?

Tags: performance, reverse-proxy, haproxy, f5

I got information about `haproxy` from [Stack Exchange Gives Back 2014](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-exchange-gives-back-2014/?cb=1) page. Stackoverflow is aso using this excellent application. After visiting [haproxy website](http://www.haproxy.org/), I found its uses like - load balancer. So,

- Does it work like F5 (reverse proxy) and can it replace F5?
- Can someone list down its all features and similar competitors application?

Comment: I use Haproxy, it is a Load Balancer, latest version offers SSL off-loading too. It supports a couple of load-balancing rules and failover. A disadvantage over F5 I can think of is it doesn't support content caching while if I am not mistaken F5 does. You can always combine other tools like Varnish to achieve this feature too. All in all, Haproxy is opensource, easy to setup and in most cases you can combine it with other tools to do everything F5 can do on its own.

Comment: thanks. Is there a single opensouce tool like `haproxy` which I can use instead `F5`?

Comment: http://www.inlab.de/articles/free-and-open-source-load-balancing-software-and-projects.html

Comment: however, I think Haproxy has been the most popular. I used to combine it with NGINX for SSL offloading, now Haproxy can stand on its own, so I expect it will gain more popularity.

Comment: Cloud providers offer a couple of cheap Load-Balancing solutions too.

Comment: Does `haproxy` also work for reverse proxy?

Comment: Of course, that is how it load balances traffic. Outside world can only see the haproxy server which works as a reverse proxy, then haproxy load balances traffic to the actual webservers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check this [list](http://www.inlab.de/articles/free-and-open-source-load-balancing-software-and-projects.html) for alternative Load Balancing tools.

Cloud providers (Amazon, Rackspace, Google Compute Engine, Softlayer etc), but also some dedicated/VM server providers, usually offer some cheap Load-Balancing solutions as a service.

Haproxy currently seems to be one of the most popular opensource software for Reverse-Proxy, Load-Balancing and failover. Latest versions 1.5+ support SSL-offloading but it still doesn't support content caching (F5 does).

The usual configuration is combining it with a Content Caching system or/and CDN and using the last version you now don't even need a separate SSL-offloader. It offers a nice set of load-balancing rules (RR, leastconn, ipHash etc), apart from their website check this nicely-formatted [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-haproxy-and-load-balancing-concepts).

Comment: Is there any demo available?

Comment: What do you mean by demo? Check their website, download it and set it up.. Read the tutorials, It's easy and straightforward